# W3 Validation Html Error

Tags: html, css, schema

**The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control.**

```
<label for="form-name">Your Phone <span>(required)</span></label>
<label for="form-name">Your Name <span>(required)</span></label>
```

i am Getting Error how Can i solve this Errors ?

Comment: umm ... add the ID of the elements or remove `for` attribute?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error validating HTML: The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567494/error-validating-html-the-for-attribute-of-the-label-element-must-refer-to-a-fo)

Comment: Your form should refer to element of form (by id), not form itself.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp

Comment: Ok trying to doing !.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an input element in your document with this id.

Example:

```
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input id="email" name="emailInput">
```